# Open new dynamic window within gridview dataview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview (called grdSearchResults) that contains links to pdfs.  The pdf url's are returned from the database but I'm not sure how to add the url to an imagebutton control within the gridview.

Here's my codebehind:

> ```
> List<SearchResults> search = _searchRepository.GetFactFileSearchResults(results);
>         grdSearchResults.DataSource = search;
>         grdSearchResults.DataBind();
> ```

And here's my aspx page code:

> ```
> <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FILE TYPE" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">  
>             <ItemTemplate>  
>                 &nbsp;<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="_imgbtnPreview" OnClientClick="<%# Container.DataItem("DownloadUrl") %>" ImageUrl="~/images/fileType_pdf.png" /> 
>             </ItemTemplate>
> ```

But this thows an error ("The server tag is not well formed")  Any idea how to fix this?  Thanks

Comment: Try to write the same in code behind,in gridview_RowDatabound event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to call a javascript function `OnClientClick`. But you haven't showed us it so it's difficult to help.

You can also set the `ImageButton's` [`ImageUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield.imageurl.aspx) in `RowDataBound` (which i normally prefer):

```
protected void grdSearchResults_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRowView rv = (DataRowView) row.DataItem;
        ImageButton imgbtnPreview = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("_imgbtnPreview");
        imgbtnPreview.ImageUrl = rv.Row.Field<String>("DownloadUrl");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your OnClientClick should be using single quote in the outer

```
OnClientClick='<%# Container.DataItem("DownloadUrl") %>'
```

And the image can be

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="x" ImageUrl='<%# String.Format("~/{0}", Eval("ImageUrl")) %>' />
```